# Unity 2D - Keep Player Object in Boundary of it's Parent Panel

Tags: unity-game-engine, boundary

In Unity i have a UI Panel which has a player object (an UI Image object).

I moving player object into planel with user inputs (keyboard or touch)

I can't keep player object in it's parent panel,

Please check below image, I want to keep player inside of Red Panel

Here is my Tried Code

```
public Camera MainCamera; //be sure to assign this in the inspector to your main camera
private Vector2 screenBounds;
private float objectWidth;
private float objectHeight;
private RectTransform pnlBackgroundTransform;


private void Start()
{
    pnlBackgroundTransform = GameObject.Find("PnlBackground").GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    screenBounds = MainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(pnlBackgroundTransform.rect.width  , pnlBackgroundTransform.rect.height , MainCamera.transform.position.z));

    objectWidth = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents.x; //extents = size of width / 2
    objectHeight = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.extents.y; //extents = size of height / 2
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 viewPos = transform.position;
    viewPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(viewPos.x, screenBounds.x * -1 + objectWidth, screenBounds.x - objectWidth);
    viewPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(viewPos.y, screenBounds.y * -1 + objectHeight, screenBounds.y - objectHeight);
    Debug.Log(screenBounds);
    Debug.Log(viewPos);
    transform.position = viewPos;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use your bottomleft corner how your player origin (0,0) and use transform.localposition instead of transform.position to move your player inside their parent panel with bound limits

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's not very usual having the player implemented as a UI element, and instead you should be implementing it outside the `UI/Canvas` system.

The `UI/Canvas` system uses a set of rules of placing and scaling to deal with responsive design. You have at least 4 values (excluding rotation) to place something on the screen: *anchor*, *pivot*, *position* and *scale*.

For example: if you want to create a square you can either set it's size in absolute pixel values or relative values (to parent). If you're using absolute values, your `UI Scale Mode`, defined on the `Canvas` object, should affect the visual results.

[image: UI absolute vs relative]

This means the `UI/Canvas` is for elements that should adapt to the screen, such as buttons, dialogs, labels, etc. Taking advantage of device parameters to improve the UX.

Outside the `UI/Canvas` system, things are directly based on Linear Algebra: you have a 3D vector space (a "World") where everything exists with an absolute size and position. Then, your Camera stretches and twists the whole world to match what your current perspective. That means your object will always have the same size, regardless of screen size.

[image: Camera size]

Now, assuming you have a very specific reason to implement your game into UI, there are a few ways you can do it. I'll assume you're using absolute values. Please note all the units used here are pixels, and the effect should be different for devices with different resolutions and sensible to the `UI Scale Mode` parameter. Also, please note I've set both anchors min and max to (0,0), the bottom left corner (default is screen center, (0.5,0.5)), in order to avoid negative coordinates.

The following script is attached to the player's UI Image.

```
public class UIMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    new private RectTransform transform;
    private Rect canvasRect;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        transform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvasRect = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().pixelRect;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Keyboard Input (Arrows)

        Vector2 move = new Vector2(0,0);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) { move.y += speed; }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) { move.y -= speed; }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) { move.x -= speed; }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) { move.x += speed; }
        transform.anchoredPosition += move;

        // Position clamping
        
        Vector2 clamped = transform.anchoredPosition;
        clamped.x = Mathf.Clamp(clamped.x, transform.rect.width / 2, canvasRect.width - transform.rect.width / 2);
        clamped.y = Mathf.Clamp(clamped.y, transform.rect.height / 2, canvasRect.height - transform.rect.height / 2);
        transform.anchoredPosition = clamped;
    }
}
```

[image: UI Movement Clamping]

Comment: While I needed this for different reason, thanks for the answer, unblocked me on a similar clamping problem.